# Where can I download previous versions of Craft?

Tags: updating

Auto-updating is great and all, but sometimes you need to roll-back to a previous version or build of Craft for whatever reason.  Where can you download these?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update April 13th, 2023**

As of Craft 4.4.6 and Craft 3.8.7, these "starter" zips are available as release artifacts on official Github releases and are automatically generated going forward.

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/releases/tag/4.4.7

---

**In Craft 2:**

You can download previous versions of Craft from https://download.craftcms.com.

Previous versions and builds of Craft are available with the following URL format in both zip and tar.gz versions:

```
http://download.craftcms.com/craft/{version}/{version}.{build}/Craft-{version}.{build}.zip (or .tar.gz)
```

For example, if you wanted Craft 2.1 build 2557 in tar.gz format, it would be

```
http://download.craftcms.com/craft/2.1/2.1.2557/Craft-2.1.2557.tar.gz
```

Note that downloading Craft releases directly still binds you to Craft’s license agreement, and keep in mind that Craft does not support rolling back to previous versions automatically.

If you’ve already updated your site past a certain release and want to go back to it, you’ll need to find and restore a database backup that was created with the version you’re going back to.

**In Craft 3:**

You can download previous Craft 3 versions in several ways:

- From pre-built packages in this format:

`http://download.craftcms.com/craft/{majorVersion}/Craft-{majorVersion}.{minorVersion}.zip (or .tar.gz)`

For example:

```
http://download.craftcms.com/craft/3.0/Craft-3.0.26.1.zip (or .tar.gz)
```

- Directly from the [Craft Github repo release](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/releases) page
- Since Craft 3 is [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) based, you can modify your `composer.json`'s `craftcms/cms` line to install the previous version you're looking for.

Comment: you knew the answer to this question all along!

Comment: This is pretty slick.

Comment: Hey Brad any ideas why the latest 2.0 url isn't working? This one here: http://download.buildwithcraft.com/craft/2.0/2.0.2551/Craft-2.0.2551.tar.gz

Comment: Ignore me - I tried .zip as I seemed to remember downloads used to zips only and it worked...

Comment: We only started generating .tar.gz files sometime in the 2.1 release cycle, if I recall. Anything before that will only be zips.