# How do you downgrade Craft

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to test a new plugin in development, is there any easy way to downgrade the version of craft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/223/where-can-i-download-previous-versions-of-craft/224#224) for how you can download previous versions of Craft.

All you need to do is replace the existing app folder with the one you just downloaded and restore a database backup that has the same build/version numbers in its `craft_info` table.