# Issues migrating Craft site to a new host

Tags: migration

We've tried moving an existing, live Craft site to a new host (where we currently just have http access via an IP). We simply copied all files (all 'craft' files, the index.php file and our related assets) across to the new host and updated permissions where necessary. We then moved across the DB and updated config settings to connect to it.

However, something is wrong. On the front end we get this message:

```
Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.
```

And when trying to access the CP, all we get is this message:

```
Oops!

Craft does not support backtracking to this version. Please upload Craft 2670 or later.
```

No idea what this means. As well, the version that the message references (2670) is the version we have installed on the live site and are trying to migrate across. Any help would be much appreciated - and I can share the dev URL non-publicly if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the database you restored on the new server isn't matching the files that are in place on that server.

Check the `craft/app/Info.php` file's `CRAFT_BUILD` and `CRAFT_VERSION` numbers and make sure they match what's in the `version` and `build` in the `craft_info` table in the database.

If you need to download a previous version of Craft to get a different build/version of the files, you can do so like [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/223/where-can-i-download-previous-versions-of-craft/224#224).

Comment: Yep - our bad - we moved files from a wrong branch for an older version of Craft. Deployed the 2670 version files and all is good. Thanks Brad.

Comment: No worries... glad to help!