# Can I auto-update to a specific version of Craft?

Tags: updating, auto-updates

Is it possible to **auto-update to a specific version** of Craft CMS – in particular, to 2.4.2726, the last version prior to 2.5?

I'd like to update some sites that haven't got the latest builds, but I'd prefer to wait for the confirmations of plugin developers regarding compatibility with the changes in 2.5. Can I easily move up to the latest 2.4.x release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to *auto*-update to a specific version of Craft, but it is possible to *manually* update to one.

You'd just need to [download](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/223/where-can-i-download-previous-versions-of-craft) the version you want to update to, then perform a [manual](https://craftcms.com/docs/updating#manually-updating) update.