# Update failed, restoring from app.bak?

Tags: auto-updates

Running Craft version 2.3, build 2644, schema version 2.3.4... we clicked "update" and got an error screen that looks like the install screen that simply says "oops".

How can I restore my site from the files that are in the (automatically generated) folder "app.bak"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore your database from your pre-update attempt database backup that you (hopefully) made.  Assuming you've got the the [backupDbOnUpdate](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#backupDbOnUpdate) config setting set to `true`, Craft made one for you in `craft/storage/runtime/backups` as well.

You can also download any previous version of Craft's files via: [Where can I download previous versions of Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/223/where-can-i-download-previous-versions-of-craft)

Just replace the existing `craft/app` folder with the fresh one you downloaded and delete `app.bak`.  I wouldn't recommend restoring directly from `app.bak` because depending on where your update failed, it could be in an inconsistent state.

I'd recommend doing a [manual update](https://craftcms.com/docs/updating#manually-updating) when you're ready to update again as you probably ran into your server's max execution time or memory limit (which tends to happen on these larger updates).